# Exec(): Limit accesses

Tags: python-3.x, security, exec, return-value

I'm putting source code into a database and I'll call the Exec () function. The user will not have direct access to this code, but for security I would limit my functions only to what you really need. I used this code:

```
exposed_methods = {'rule': rule, 'print': print, 'return': 'return'}
exec([CODE_STRING], {'__builtins__': None}, exposed_methods)
```

But this is too limiting, I can not seem to get back to editing a variable in memory or returning something. Here is a simple test:

```
string = """
if rule.test(True):
    variable_test = 'test1.1'
    return 'test1.2'
else:
    variable_test = 'test2.1'
    return 'test2.2'
"""

exposed_methods = {'rule': rule, 'print': print, 'return': 'return'}
exec(string, {'__builtins__': None}, exposed_methods)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in
>   
>   File "", line 3 
>   SyntaxError: 'return' outside
>   function

The variable is not in memory and the method does not return found

Comment: So the **real immediate problem** is "return outside a function" and not about "limiting access". This would not change if using the basic form of `exec`.

Comment: Anyway, perhaps pass in a mutable 'context' object? `context = {'returnValue': None}`. (And `return` is not a function, so just scrub that entirely..)

Comment: @user2864740 I can not set a variable, it is not created or changed. If remove the limiter, this works normally. I would not like to launch the system without limits, it is for a great customer.

Comment: `exposed_methods = {'rule': rule, 'print': print, 'context': context}` -- see "context" from above, how could this be used. Or, consider something like `exposed_methods = {'rule': rule, 'print': print, 'setReturnValue': thisFunctionSetsAReturnValueThatCanBeAccessed}`?

Comment: In both cases *no* local variable is returned and *no* `return` statement is used from the code-in-a-string. If wishing the "return" *statement* to work, wrap the code 'in a function' (part of the exec'ed string) and use one of the above methods to "export" the result: `def wrapper(): /* indented client code */; context.returnValue = wrapper();`

Comment: @user2864740 Did you take any tests? It does not work.

Comment: @user2864740 I tried to edit a variable that exists. I also tried calling a function that edits an existing variable. None works when I put restrictions.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/VioletredPushyCache - I don't need to "try" it, because I'm confident in how it works. The supplied 'context object/dict' is **modified in the exec** and then *accessed from the caller*. Similarly, this can be dressed up in a simulated wrapper method, as stated later - but you gotta understand these concepts first :}

Comment: @user2864740 Now I understand the working mechanism. Many thanks for your example, can you make a "real" comment to mark as a valid response?